# why use an 'apply' function in this situation?

Tags: javascript

in Chrome's console,

```
> $$
bound: function ()
{
    return document.querySelectorAll.apply(document, arguments)
}
```

why is this code like this?
what's difference with

```
   return document.querySelectorAll(arguments)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arguments` is an array-like object.

Calling `document.querySelectorAll(arguments)` will pass the entire array as a single parameter.
Calling `querySelectorAll.apply(document, arguments)` will pass each item in the array as a separate parameter.

In this particular case, it's not very useful, since `querySelectorAll` can only take one argument.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.apply()` ensures that the arguments supplied to `bound()` are *unwrapped* before being supplied to `querySelectorAll()`.

Without this, the effect of invoking:

```
bound('foo');
```

would be to call

```
document.querySelectorAll(['foo']);
```